# Missing vote-to-close privilege after beta?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I had the requisite reputation for voting for close during the beta phase (according to the reputation page, my rep exceeded 500 on Nov 2, while the official launch was around Nov 11, when the privilege cap was raised to 3000). I distinctly remember exercising it once during the beta.

Now I noticed I no longer have the privilege.

Is this `[status-by-design]`? I was under the impression that privileges are not taken away once they are obtained. Perhaps this has already been answered on meta.SO, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/600/1235).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* that this is "by design" since one of the criteria for getting out of beta is having enough users with enough power and the discussion always centred on the power that users will have *after the beta ends*.  So I think that you have to re-earn these higher privileges.  Sorry.

Comment: Oh well. Not that I particularly need higher privileges, but occasionally this one comes in handy. Guess I'll need to answer me some questions on the parent site..

Comment: It certainly is useful on the site to have lots of high-rep users.  So absolutely: go back to the parent site and answer some questions!

Answer (score 3):

In the private beta, everyone has rights to edit and close/reopen; they only miss the 10k-tools rights.  And then nearly everyone loses these rights.

This is very much [status-bydesign]: the need for enough 200, 2k and 3k rep. users was emphasised in the desiderata for graduating sites.